# Chrome Extension. How i can embed a js into iframe ( cross - origin ) and send location.href back to top

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension

I have a website which can load another site and extension to make a screenshot. I want to get the current URL of the iframe and then send it to the top frame. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: If both the top frame and the iframe have your content script running then you can use either DOM top.postMessage or extension messaging relay via background/event page. OTOH in some cases you can get the URL via chrome.webNavigation.getAllFrames in a background/event/popup page.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the tip. I'll check the docs. Could you also give an advise how I can determine from which exactly iframe script was executed? Because I need only one particular iframe not all of them.

Comment: Depends on your identification criteria. If you know the DOM element in the content script you can postMessage to iframe.contentWindow with a unique message that will be received in that iframe's content script so it'll send the URL back to the top frame. If you have a rule for the URL you can use regexps.